# How can I properly link and call assembly code through extern functions in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to write a Rust wrapper for some assembly code. As such, have some assembly code that I want to link and call through `extern` functions in my Rust project. Initially, I tried adding the assembly code in the `build.rs` file using `cc::Build::new()`, and it worked for `cargo build` and `cargo run`, but not for `cargo test` -- it had a linking error. Then, I tried using `std::process::Command` to compile the assembly code, but while it worked initially for `cargo build`, `cargo run` and `cargo test`, it stopped working altogether for some reason.

What is the proper way to link assembly code and call it through extern functions in Rust?

Here's the `build.rs` file I used initially:

```rs
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("asm/lib1.s")
        .compile("lib1");

    cc::Build::new()
        .file("asm/lib2.s")
        .compile("lib2");
}
```

And here's the `build.rs` file I tried with `std::process::Command`:

```rs
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    Command::new("nasm")
        .args(&[
            "-f",
            "elf64",
            "-o",
            "lib1.o",
            "asm/lib1.s",
        ])
        .status()
        .unwrap();

    Command::new("nasm")
        .args(&[
            "-f",
            "elf64",
            "-o",
            "lib2.o",
            "asm/lib2.s",
        ])
        .status()
        .unwrap();
}
```

My `Cargo.toml` file looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "wrapper-rs"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
uint = "0.9.5"

[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0.79"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you manually call `nasm` you have to [tell cargo to link to your objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script) `cc::Build` does that for you.